# Validating mask input date in jquery while entering date

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mask

I am using jquery mask plugin for date entry in textbox and the date format is `MM/DD/YYYY`. I want to do the validation while entering the date. Suppose if I enter month as `13` at that time it should alert me month is invalid, like that I need to do for date and year. My code is below,

```
$("#txtDate").mask("99/99/9999", { autoclear: false })

<input id="txtDate" type="text" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"/>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't you think showing alert will be irritating?  using this plugin you can set the numbers that can be entered, if user types something out of that given configuration then the input is not considered at all..